# Clickonce exe won't run on my Windows 10 PC

Tags: c#, clickonce

My applications installed using clickonce won't run on my Windows 10 PC. They do run perfectly on other Windows 10 PC's(They used to work on my PC).
I've tried to run the exe file directly from the clickonce folder and it won't run either.
I've seen some mention of a Kensington mouse issue ( something about paths of over 128 characters ) but I don't have any Kensington software installed.
I don't get any error message I just get the timer and file explorer just hangs.
The apps run perfectly in debug mode from Visual Studio and directly from the debug folder ( possibly the shorter path ! ).
Can anyone help?
Thanks,
Jim.

Comment: Have you looked at the Application log in the Event Viewer?  Windows should be logging something there if the application is hanging, and that may provide some more clues as to your issue.